# How to identify a Page in a PDF

Tags: algorithm, pdf

I have an app where users upload PDF docs to a webserver. Each Page in that PDF  doc has certain app specific "interesting properties"  which the app infers by reading the content in the page.
This information is stored in a DB and needs to be presented to the user. The issue is that users can delete , insert and change the page order, as well as make changes to the values of these interesting properties so page number is not a good way to track the properties of a page.
What is a good way to make sure that we can track this.

Comment: _Interesting properties_ of (pages of) documents in [PDF](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html) deserve to be represented in the file as metadata (XMP, RDF, …) rather than inferred. Taking _this_ to be the user changes mentioned, what/who is _we_ (and what is the scale for _good_)? Objects in a PDF file have internal (linear) versioning.

Comment: How are those values represented? AcroForm form widgets? In that case search for the form element, not the page.

Comment: no its more like the content of the pages. So if the page has certain text in it it becomes a certain page type ( say an invoice page ). In that case the invoice amount ( for example) is an interesting piece of information 
We have a parsing phase were code gets all this information out of the PDF page . I suppose we could store that back into the Page itself but somehow a DB seems better especially if you want to do reporting etc later on ( like total up the invoice amounts etc )

Comment: How may the users change the document? You make it sound like they can change everything they want. In that case it is diffiicult to recognize a page because there is no sure constant. Or are the tools of the users limited to a given set of operations which touch only part of the PDF structure?

Comment: @mkl they can insert pages , delete pages, reorder pages

Comment: But didn't you say they can also change content? And what kind of changed can they do? And what kind of pages can they insert?